# Как определить свободный COM порт

Tags: c#, windows, com-port

На компьютере в реестре по следующему пути HKLM:\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM прописаны два устройства \Device\Serial0 и \Device\Serial1
Следовательно они привязаны каждый к своему COM порту COM1 и COM3, но только к одному из них устройство подключено физически.

Прошу подсказать как в Windows c помощью C# определить какой из этих COM портов свободен, а на каком находится устройство ?

Comment: Попробывать пообщаться с устройством по портам перебором, если не отвечает по таймауту, брать следующий

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что вам нужно знать какие порты свободны физически(в них ни чего не воткнуто)?

Comment: @Vasek Да, понимаете правильно.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы работало с любым устройством?

Comment: Желательно с любым

Comment: На 100% это ни как достоверно не определить. Можно попробовать DSR/DTR и CTS/RTS handshaking. Но не все железки это поддерживают и в добавок может быть воткнут RS-485.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что пришло в голову, это пробовать Port.Open() в блоке try catch (код с англоязычного форума).

```
var portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            foreach (var port in portNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    // открыть порт
                }
                catch
                {
                    // если порт занят, вылетит System.UnauthorizedAccessException
                }
            }
```

Comment: `если порт занят, вылетит System.UnauthorizedAccessException` - вылетит скорее всего про тайм-аут или доступ запрещен.

Comment: @NewView только что пробовал запустить. Открыл порт через Terminal и попытался открыть подключение из шарпа. Вылетело System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: Значит в CLR ещё куча логических багов :)

Comment: Получается по вылетевшему Exception смогу определять занят порт или нет? Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: @Ivan Да, если порт занят, подключение к нему будет вызывать Exception.

Comment: @Ivan [смогу определять занят порт или нет] Вы сможете определить открыт ли порт другой программой или нет. Занят порт или нет (то есть воткнут ли в порт кабель и висит ли на кабеле другое устройство) в общем случае определить нельзя. Только зная какое именно устройство висит на кабеле можно послать в устройство команду и, получив ожидаемый ответ, определить наличие устройства.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за помощь.